# aspx page on Sharepoint error: Function Expected only when rendering datatable

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have been building a reporting page in sharepoint with dc and crossfilter.

Right now on my page, I have 5 pie charts that render with no problem. However, when I tried to add a dc datatable to the page to show results of the charts as they are filtered, I get a javascript error on "resultsChart.render();"

Because no errors are given when I render each of the pie charts, I assume this to mean that something is off with the datatable object, or that I cannot call render() on that object (whatever it thinks it is).

Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js" type="text/javascript">          
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.6/dc.min.js" type="text/javascript">   

//connect to sharepoint site (change this URL to redirect)

var siteUrl = 'path';
var masterData = [];

//retrieve list data from above sharepoint site based on List Name
                function retrieveListItems() {

                    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
                    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Upcoming');
                    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();                    
                    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query></Query></View>");   

                    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
                    clientContext.load(collListItem);
                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
                        );

                    }
                //on query success      

                function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

                    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

                    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) { 

                        var data = {};
                        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

                        //set field keys on array objects

                        data.project = oListItem.get_item('Project_x0020_Type');
                        data.stoplight = oListItem.get_item('Stoplight');
                        data.appmgr = oListItem.get_item('AIT_x0020_App_x0020_Manager');    
                        data.compdate = oListItem.get_item('Completion_x0020_Due_x0020_Date');
                        data.ait = oListItem.get_item('AIT_x0020_Number');
                        data.lob = oListItem.get_item('Business_x0020_Area');
                        data.sublob = oListItem.get_item('Business_x0020_Sub_x0020_Area');




                        masterData.push(data);

                    }//end while

                    var projectChart = dc.pieChart("#project", "project");
                    var stoplightChart = dc.pieChart("#stoplight", "stoplight");                        
                    var appmgrChart = dc.pieChart("#appmgr", "appmgr");
                    var lobChart = dc.pieChart("#lob", "lob");
                    var sublobChart = dc.pieChart("#sublob", "sublob"); 
                    var resultChart = dc.dataTable("#result_table", "result");                  

                    var ndx = crossfilter(masterData),
                        projectType = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.project;}),
                        stoplight = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.stoplight;}),
                        appMgr = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.appmgr;}),
                        compdate = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.compdate;}),
                        lob = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.lob;}),
                        sublob = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.sublob;})
                        projectTypeGroup = projectType.group();
                        stoplightGroup = stoplight.group(),
                        appMgrGroup = appMgr.group(),
                        compDateGroup = compdate.group(),
                        lobGroup = lob.group(),
                        sublobGroup = sublob.group();

                    projectChart
                    .dimension(projectType)
                    .group(projectTypeGroup)
                    .width(200)
                    .height(200)
                    .innerRadius(75)


                    stoplightChart
                    .dimension(stoplight)
                    .group(stoplightGroup)
                    .width(200)
                    .height(200)
                    .innerRadius(75)


                    appmgrChart
                    .dimension(appMgr)
                    .group(appMgrGroup)
                    .width(200)
                    .height(200)
                    .innerRadius(75)


                    lobChart
                    .dimension(lob)
                    .group(lobGroup)
                    .width(300)
                    .height(300)
                    .innerRadius(117)

                    sublobChart 
                    .dimension(sublob)
                    .group(sublobGroup)
                    .width(200)
                    .height(200)
                    .innerRadius(75)

                    resultChart
                    .dimension(compdate)
                    .group(compDateGroup)
                    .columns([
                        function(d) { return d.ait},
                        function(d) { return d.project},
                        function(d) { return d.stoplight},
                        function(d) { return d.compdate}
                            ])
                    .size(100);

                    projectChart.render();
                    stoplightChart.render();
                    appmgrChart.render();
                    lobChart.render();
                    sublobChart.render();
                    resultChart.render();






                }

                function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                 alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                }

            SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, 'sp.js');


</script>
```

Any and all help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. According to [the dc.dataTable documentation](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html), you cannot use a crossfilter group as the .group attribute on a datatable. Instead, you must explicitly use a function there.

So it should be

```
resultChart
                .dimension(compdate)
                .group(function(d) { return d.compdate;})
                .columns([
                    function(d) { return d.ait},
                    function(d) { return d.project},
                    function(d) { return d.stoplight},
                    function(d) { return d.compdate}
                        ])
                .size(100);
```

Instead of

```
 resultChart
                .dimension(compdate)
                .group(compDateGroup)
                .columns([
                    function(d) { return d.ait},
                    function(d) { return d.project},
                    function(d) { return d.stoplight},
                    function(d) { return d.compdate}
                        ])
                .size(100);
```

Comment: Thanks for following up. Yes, that's a common annoyance. Strangely enough, you can pass a group as the dimension parameter. It's a weird world.